# Scala - Currying and default arguments

Tags: scala, arguments, default-value, currying

I have a function with two parameter lists that I am trying to partially apply and use with currying. The second parameter list contains arguments that all have default values (but not implicit). Something like this:

```
 def test(a: Int)(b: Int = 2, c: Int = 3) { println(a + ", " + b + ", " + c); }
```

Now, the following is all fine:

```
 test(1)(2, 3);
 test(1)(2);
 test(1)(c=3);
 test(1)();
```

Now if I define:

```
 def partial = test(1) _;
```

Then the following can be done:

```
 partial(2, 3);
```

Can someone explain why I can't omit some/all arguments in 'partial' as follows:

```
 partial(2);
 partial(c=3);
 partial();
```

Shouldn't writing "partial" behave essentially the same way as "test(1)"? Can someone please help me figure out a way to achieve this?

Please help, I'm desperate!

**EDIT** - Since I can't answer my own question within 24 hours, I'll post my own answer here:

This is the best I could do myself so far:

```
class Test2(val a: Int) {
   def apply(b: Int = 2, c: Int = 3) { println(a + ", " + b + ", " + c); }
}

def test2(a: Int) = new Test2(a);
def partial2 = test2(1); // Note no underscore

test2(1)(2, 3);
test2(1)(2);
test2(1)(c=3);
test2(1)();

partial2(2, 3)
partial2(2);
partial2(c=3);
partial2();
```

This way it works...

Comment: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.user/36288

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the best I could do myself so far:

```
class Test2(val a: Int) {
   def apply(b: Int = 2, c: Int = 3) { println(a + ", " + b + ", " + c); }
}

def test2(a: Int) = new Test2(a);
def partial2 = test2(1); // Note no underscore

test2(1)(2, 3);
test2(1)(2);
test2(1)(c=3);
test2(1)();

partial2(2, 3)
partial2(2);
partial2(c=3);
partial2();
```

This way it works...

Answer (score 7):

The type inference engine gives to `partial` the type of what comes next; i.e., the eta expansion `test(1) _`. You can see e.g. in the REPL that `partial` has type `(Int, Int) => Unit`, whereas `test` has type `(a: Int)(b: Int,c: Int)Unit`. The result of the eta expansion is a `Function` object, which does not carry any argument names with it (as it is possible to define `Function` with anonymous parameters).

To fix this, you have to define `partial` as follows:

```
def partial(b: Int = 2, c: Int = 3) = test(1)(b,c)
```

Maybe you'll want to factor out the default values where both `test` and `partial` can reach them to make sure they stay equal. But I know of no trick to avoid repeating the names of the parameters without introducing extra overhead like creating of new objects, etc.

Comment: The `Function` object does carry argument names but those are the argument names defined in `Function2` You can actually invoke the example given by @Desperate this way: `partial(v1 = 2, v2 = 3)`.

Comment: I figured it had to do with the compiler not creating new classes for functions like this but using "generic" Function2 instead. Otherwise it could have stored all the info it needs in annotations.

The whole point was to avoid repeating argument names/list, though :(

Comment: @Moritz, I realize that, but that's not useful at all when one wants to preserve proper names. This truly is a deficiency if not a defect of the language. I never understood why is Scala trying to reuse pre-created Function<N> classes instead of generating them as needed. I know that would generate more classes, but it would be both the correct thing to do and useful in the end.

On a side note, I'll try generating a new Function-like object of my own, with 'apply' method in it...

Comment: @Desperate I did not say it was useful - it could even be harmful if your parameters happen to have the same names in a different order. Scala actually does generate a subclass of `FunctionN` cases like this but returning a specialized subtype here would make overloading quite tricky.

Comment: This is the best I could do myself so far:

    class Test2(val a: Int) {
       def apply(b: Int = 2, c: Int = 3) { println(a + ", " + b + ", " + c); }
    }
   
    def test2(a: Int) = new Test2(a);
    def partial2 = test2(1); // Note no underscore
   
    test2(1)(2, 3);
    test2(1)(2);
    test2(1)(c=3);
    test2(1)();
    
    partial2(2, 3)
    partial2(2);
    partial2(c=3);
    partial2();

This way it works...

Comment: @Desperate/@Learner Cool! Please post it as an answer too, it will be more readable.

Comment: I want to... but I am not allowed yet (less than 24h since I posted the question)

Answer (score 2):

Following up on your comment, here's a more compact way to write it:

```
def test(a: Int) = new {
  def apply(b: Int = 2, c: Int = 3) {
    println(a + ", " + b + ", " + c)
  }
}
```

This is a bit more compact than your proposal, but is less efficient, as any call to the inner `apply` will occur through reflection, as with structural types. Actually, the return type of `test` is a structural type:

```
 java.lang.Object{def apply(b: Int,c: Int): Unit; def apply$default$1: 
 Int @scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance; def apply$default$2: Int 
 @scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance}
```